# XMLStreamWriter does not convert "\n" to "&#xA;" when writing attributes

Tags: xml, escaping, newline, xmlstreamwriter

I am trying to write an XML file using XMLStreamWriter. The problem is that I have an attribute value with "\r\n".

Since I am using an XML writer, I was expecting the writer to escape "\n" to `&#xA;` and "\r" to `&#xD;`, but that does not happen. 
That causes the resulting file to have the attribute value splitted in multiple lines, and my application (based on EMF) ignores the new lines.

What I would like to do is to write the attribute's value with `&#xA;` and `&#xD;`. How can I do that?

Comment: Have you tried any methods of escaping the characters before you write to the file?

Comment: I tried to replace "\n" with "&#xA;" and "\r" with "&#xD". In this case, XMLStreamWriter will replace the "&" by "&amp;". Therefore, the file will end up with "&amp;#xA;" instead of "\n". 
The problem is, i gess, that both "\n" and "&#xA;" represent the same byte (10) and what I need is XMLStreamWriter to write that byte as "&#xA;" instead of "\n".